# Proof of $ x^5 \leq \frac{56}{3} + \frac{5}{3} x^3 \Rightarrow x \leq 2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, absolute-value

I have a problem (but unfortunately no solution to it) where I have to prove that for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ which satisfies $ x^5 \leq \frac{56}{3} +\frac{5}{3}x^3 $, holds $x \leq 2 $ . So to put it another way:
$$ x^5 \leq \frac{56}{3} + \frac{5}{3} x^3 \Rightarrow x \leq 2$$

rewritten this gives

$$ 3x^5 \leq 56 + 5x^3 \Rightarrow x \leq 2$$

How do I have to proceed? An induction works only with integers, for a direct proof I don't have the idea. My proof sketch was this, but it's obvisouly false :/

$$3x^5 \leq 56 + 5x^3 \Rightarrow x \leq 2 \\ x^5 \leq 56 + 5x^3 \\ x^2 \leq 56/x^3 + 5 \\ x^2 - \frac{56}{x^3} \leq 5 $$

Comment: Do you have access to tools from calculus?  Do you know what the derivative represents?

Comment: I'm not allowed to use it :/

Comment: Why not?  It is the easiest option and nearly every college course sequence introduces proof writing after having introduced calculus.  If you are not allowed to use it... then what *are* you allowed to use?

Comment: Quick sketch of proof with calculus tools: Consider the contrapositive, that $x>2\implies x^5>\frac{56}{3}+\frac{5}{3}x^3$.  At $x=2$ the two sides are equal.  The derivatives of each side are $5x^4$ and $5x^2$ respectively.  Remembering the context that $x>2$ we know that the derivative of the LHS is always strictly greater than the derivative of the RHS, proving what we wanted.  Q.E.D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{equation*}
x^{5}\leq \frac{56}{3}+\frac{5}{3}x^{3}
\end{equation*}
is equivalent to
\begin{equation*}
3x^{5}-5x^{3}-56\leq 0\text{,}
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
3x^{5}-5x^{3}-56=\left( 3x^{4}+6x^{3}+7x^{2}+14x+28\right) \times \left(
x-2\right) \text{.}
\end{equation*}
Notice that $3x^{4}+6x^{3}+7x^{2}+14x+28>0$ holds for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$
since we have
\begin{equation*}
3x^{4}+6x^{3}+7x^{2}+14x+28=3x^{2}\left( x+1\right) ^{2}+4(x+\frac{7}{4}
)^{2}+\frac{63}{4}\text{.}
\end{equation*}
Thus, $3x^{5}-5x^{3}-56\leq 0$ is satisfied if and only if $x\leq 2$. Hope
this helps.

Comment: Your proof of the positivity of $3x^4+6x^3+7x^2+14x+28$ is not correct: you need to show that $(6x^2+7x+14)x$ is positive, if you want the sum of both terms to be positive, not just $6x^2+7x+14$. For negative $x$, this term $(6x^2+7x+14)x$ is actually negative and you have no guarantee, in your proof, that $3x^4+28$ will compensate for it. It *actually* does but your proof miss this point.

Comment: It should be fine now. Enjoy.

Answer (score 2):

Not using derivatives, you would have (on the left),

$$\forall x\in \mathbb{R}, 3x^5 - 5x^3 \leq 56$$

equivalent to, factorizing by $x^3$,

$$\forall x\in \mathbb{R}, x^3(3x^2-5)\leq 56$$

Now, suppose that $x>2$. Then, you would have $x^3>2^3=8$ and $3x^2-5>3\cdot 2^2 - 5 = 7$ and multiplying both terms (since they are positive) yields
$x^3(3x^2-5)>8\times 7=56$, thus a contradiction.

So, $x\leq 2$.